# Exclude own IP in google analytics with IP anonymization

Tags: google-analytics

For the dutch cookie law I have to use IP anonymization, but since I switched on that my own IP is not excluded anymore in Google analytics. Is there a way to exclude my own IP (for testing) in google analytics with IP anonymization?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about google analytics set up and is not programing related probably belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I readed someware that it can be solved with some javascript, thats programming...

Comment: did you try the code are you having issues with it? If so post that code and we can try to help you.

Comment: The code wasn't there, so thats why i posted the question

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  I still think that you will find more help on webmasters then hear I wouldn't be surprised if someone there hasn't had this problem before.

Comment: My take in this here: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/with-your-own-ga-requests-dont-exclude-rewrite/. If your are talking just about your own computer it might also help to simply install the opt-out plugin from Google https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout.

Answer (score 2):

When you use anonymize IP it blocks out the last octet of the IP address
You can still filter IPs but you'd need to use a regex that will filter out the whole last octet.

so, you wont just be filtering `62.225.129.64|65` but all IPs that begin with `62.225.129.` and also leave it with that begin with
[screen shot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtghM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Opt out did the job, thanks Eike!

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout